# Should self-answered questions be excluded from audits?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, self-answer

I did reviews on close on close queue, and this question came up: [Handling Julian dates in C++11/14](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33964461/694733). I voted to close as it seemed too broad, and as a result I failed an audit.

It turns out it is self-answered question. Question and answer were clearly written first and then posted.

I can't blame the poster; With the answer the question makes sense. Too much text on question would have complicated things unnecessarily, as answer already handles it. But this is not visible on review.

But if it were "normal" question, I don't think it could have been expected to get answered in the same detail. Answer is *quite* long.

So the question is:

Should the self-answered questions be excluded as a special case from audits, as they don't necessarily need to be as complete?

Comment: It looks like it is just a bad audit question and has nothing to do with being self answered.

Comment: So if this was a "normal" review instead of an audit then you would have blindly deleted a Q+A with a valuable answer.  Nice job.

Comment: @HansPassant He'd have voted to close, not deleted.  Big difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Self-answered questions are held to the same standard as regular Q&As. They are not special cases.

> With the answer the question makes sense.

Questions should make sense even if there are no answers on it. If it's a bad question, it doesn't suddenly become a good question just because the answer may be good.

The problem isn't that this was self-answered, the problem is that the question has a positive score and no down votes. That's how the system picks questions: any post with votes where all the votes are positive or all the votes are negative are potential audits.

If you feel the question is too broad you should still flag it and down vote it (the down vote will prevent it from being used in an audit again).

Answer (score 3):

Self answered questions are held to the same standard as every other question.  If the question is Too Broad, then it's Too Broad, regardless of whether the OP posts an answer or not.

Comment: Except when the likes of Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert answers it, then it is okay.  Hmm.

Comment: @HansPassant I have no idea what you're trying to say here.  Are you saying that those two people are above the rules and can post bad self answered questions, or are you trying to say that one of those two are likely to answer questions like this so we shouldn't ever close questions that are Too Broad?